# Android KeyStore parameters building

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, keystore

I'm trying to use RSA encryption with KeyStore and I need to specify Parameters for `KeyPairGenerator` and I'm lost here. `KeyPairGeneratorPair` is kinda straightforward, but I don't understand `KeyGenParameterSpec` for API>=23

That's what I did, I think I got everything in `else` part, but now I'm confused about `KeyGenParameterSpec`

**What exactly public exponent in `RSAKeyGenParameterSpec` is?**

**What Digests in `.setDigests` should i specify?**

**There's also `.setBlockMode()` method to call, and since I'm using RSA and `RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding`which block mode to set? ECB, CBC?**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                generator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("PrivateKey", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                        .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + "PrivateKey"))
                        .setCertificateNotBefore(calendar.getTime())
                        .setCertificateNotAfter(endCalendar.getTime())
                        .setKeySize(2048).build());
            } else {
                generator.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setAlias("PrivateKey")
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + "PrivateKey"))
                        .setStartDate(calendar.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(endCalendar.getTime())
                        .setKeySize(2048).build()      

 );
            }

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `setDigests()` sets digest method for your padding mode and `setBlockMode()` sets encryption mode which depends on your work.

I think you have set a lot of unnecessary field. For example I use this method to create my own `RSA` key:

```
public boolean createKey() {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA,
                "AndroidKeyStore"
        );

        mKeyStore.load(null);
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder =
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        MY_KEY,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).
                setKeySize(MY_KEYLEN).
                setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP).
                setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256);

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(builder.build());
        keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I created this key to use with `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` algorithm.

Comment: Oh, so i don't need to specify those fields at all. One more thing, how do I know which Digest to use? Like SHA256 or SHA512? If i use `OAEPWithSHA1` does that mean that i should use `SHA1`?

Comment: @Wiktor depends on cipher that you want to use. For example I created this key to use in `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding`. This algorithm needs `SHA-256` digest.